# How Does Rails Determine This id's Value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Coming from Java, a highly explicit language, to RoR, which uses a very terse syntax, is easy for the most part, but I'm struggling to understand a few of the things that are going on behind the scenes.

In the code below, how does Rails assign **product_id:** a value? Couldn't product.id be used instead? What does the **product_id:** mean exactly in this context? Where does its value come from?

In the view:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div class="entry">
<%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
<h3><%= product.title %></h3>
<%= sanitize(product.description) %>
<div class="price_line">
  <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price, unit: '$') %></span>
  <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Is it because of the attr_accessible statements I gave in my line_items model?:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `belongs_to :product` is what gives your model (LineItem) this attribute. So now you can reference the parent product (that this LineItem belongs to), by doing for example `LineItem.find(1).product_id`, which would return the same as doing `LineItem.find(1).product.id`.

Rails uses this conventional attribute (product_id) as it directly maps to the table column. Check your schema.rb file, you will find it there, inside the line_items table.

Comment: LineItem.find(1).product_id will return the id of the product which is stored in the LineItem table. So if the Product is somehow deleted from the Product Table LineItem.find(1).product.id will throw an error since LineItem.product = nil and nil.id is therefore undefined (no Object can be retrieved using the id specified in LineItem), so it can return the same but not in all cases

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that you have a route that expects a `product_id`, and the "Add to Cart" link is linking to that route's URL, and passing the id for `product` in that URL. I belive doing `line_items_path(product_id: product)` is the same as doing `line_items_path(product_id: product.id)`.

Comment: Also, you probably have a file `app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb` with at least one action that deals with a `product_id`. That file would probably tell you more than the `LineItem` model.

Comment: Yeah, I'd look under `def create` in `line_items_controller.rb`. That's almost certainly what's getting called when that "Add to Cart" link is getting clicked. Maybe you already knew that.

Answer (score 0):

It'll call the `#to_param` method, which by default returns the id.

As you come from Java, I'd say it's similar as when you do `System.out.println(anObject)` which calls implicitly the `#toString()` method

Answer (score 0):

`product_id` is a parameter that `line_items_path` route is expecting. You can just pass an object instead of setting it manually:

```
line_items_path(product)
```

Result should be the same. If you rename it in your routes, it would break your views, so it's better not to manually set it.

Answer (score 0):

```
line_items_path(product_id: product)
```

Is equivalent to

```
line_items_path(:product_id => product)
```

Which is the same as

```
line_items_path({:product_id => product})
```

In this specific case `product_id` behaves like a symbol literal ( normally you need the leading `:` or %s[]). This alternative, more json-like hash syntax was added in ruby 1.9.

Comment: Sorry for raising this old post, but why can't we write `line_items_path(product.id)` instead of `line_items_path(product_id: product)`? Because the parameters must be an hash?

Comment: because in general rails wouldn't know that the id you were giving it referred to a product (depends on how the route is defined though)